# Odoo Server problems

Tags: odoo

Dears,
I have a problem in odoo server ,
when open server for first time in day , I find white page no data.
when remove database and create a new database , it resolve and work well .
I resolve this problem finally not appear again .
thank you.

Comment: how did you install the Odoo and the database?

Comment: i downloaded it and installed by git clone ,
first it worked correctly.
when download new model from outside Odoo server and install .
database is defective so i removed database and this model and installed a new database .